# Cannot connect to WiFi after an upgrade (Ubuntu 20.04.1)

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04

A problem I encountered with the last update made by my computer. Indeed, I am having problems with my computer since the end of the update (since the restart to be more precise).

Currently, it is running under version 20.04.1 and the last update was made yesterday. The computer works, but it can no longer connect to WiFi. Which is relatively inconvenient.

It displays the following message:

> Connection failure The activation of the network connection failed

This is my wireless info reported by my computer:

- [while connected via Ethernet and WiFi working](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XSKHrxpN3y/)
- [with disconnected Ethernet and WiFi failing](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2cHJHtJ9dv/)

The problem is probably not the Wifi, because my other devices that have not had recent updates still manage to connect, and My computer's wired connection works (I borrowed my roommate's ethernet cable). So I would like to know if you have any idea what is wrong.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please always post in English on this site. Your WiFi problem could be related to the system update. However, you should provide more information about your WiFi hardware, see [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/q/425155/250300)

Comment: Okay, I 'll try it, but I haven't have a very good english level.
there is the report edited by my computer (with etheral link)
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/88JMxrTRgt/

Comment: Thank you for the report. I am not an expert regarding WiFi on Ubuntu but I find your WiFi working according to your report. Could you disconnect Ethernet and try again? If your internet connection stops working, please create another wireless info and [edit] your question to include the link.

Comment: _“I can't launch the report editing without eternet cable, because, computer says that he don't know the address without internet acces.”_ After you download (`wget`) the script once, it should remain on your machine. In the folder where you have downloaded it, simply run `./wireless-info`.

Comment: Okay so there is the wireless report
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2cHJHtJ9dv/